# My password challenge problem

Tags: linux

We are challenged to write a program that prompts the user to enter a password. The right password is " I Love Java programming "
And it should be that the password has a single space before and after just like what I've written. Now, there is a condition, that if a user enters more than 2 or more spaces before or after the right password, the computer will still accept it!,,can u help me?

Comment: homework? Perhaps if you could show us the code you have written so far? People don't generally like to just write your code for you...

Comment: Agreed with Mitch, Site is for solving Programming problems and not for asking others to do homework. buddy u gotta learn programming to be good programmer. :)

Comment: What language are you working in?  I would guess Java, but that is just a guess, as that would run on any computer.

Comment: It's possible s/he just needs a little help getting started (i.e., not sure what algorithm to use). It's not really fair of you guys to assume that s/he just wants free code for a homework assignment. (Though now I see the homework tag ^_^) At any rate, I believe that the users of this site should be professional and not discriminate too much against questionable, er, questions. In my opinion, a professional answer should always be provided where feasible, whenever the question creator is not being entirely 100% ridiculous.

Comment: @libarme Satoona  To get good help, here on SO, but also in life in general, you need to ask good questions:  Questions which are precise (you did that) but also questions that indicate that you have tried to think about the problem in some level of detail, maybe that you have tried something.  So go ahead and add such info (a bit of the code you are writing, or maybe a verbal description with a few keywords ex: I'm thinking about storing the password in a character array but strlen() doesn't seem to report the right value. etc.

Comment: @Platinum Azure   The professional attitude in the case of help with homework is to be mentor of sort to the pupils; to nudge them in the right direction but to ensure they put in some effort/thought of their own.

Comment: @mjv True, but I don't think some of the comments earlier than mine were professional at all. "You gotta learn programming to be a good programmer" really? Sure, that's definitely a true statement, but it's unhelpful to post that without also giving the sort of "nudge" you are talking about. Now, I like to think I did what you had suggested with my answer (see below), though I might have been a little TOO helpful on your view.

Comment: @Platinum  Agreed. (I had missed this unhelpful comment) BTW, you did good, +6 and counting.  Karma goes around ;-)

Comment: @mjv: Ah, no worries then. Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Answer (score 6):

What language?

Here's a language-agnostic answer to start with.

You have a few options here.

- You can write a little "state machine" (which I here use very informally to describe some kind of iterator over all the characters in the password, that expects a certain pattern to the input), in which you check first for 1 or more spaces, then the string in the middle, then 1 or more spaces.
- You can use a regular expression. Depending on your language, there might be built-in support for regular expressions-- go on Google and type " regular expressions" to find out more.
- Many languages have string "trim" functions, which essentially get rid of leading or trailing junk characters such as whitespace. You can check the first and last characters of the string to make sure that they are whitespace, and then do a trim and check for "I Love Java programming" (no spaces). This guarantees that the password is correct in central content and surrounded by AT LEAST one space on each side.

Since this appears to be a homework question and I don't feel like writing code for you, I'm just going to leave you with this and you can figure out how to implement it in the language you need to use.

Either as you code or afterwords, make sure you take the time to figure out WHAT each of the methods I have proposed means (that is, HOW each algorithm works) and also WHY it (the algorithm) works. Being able to understand why will help you solve similar problems in the future and will also lead you to come up with your own algorithms for different classes of problems as you gain more experience.

Comment: Oh, and to other users of SO: Please don't knock me too heavily for using "state machine" in an informal (and likely technically incorrect) way. I'm using it in a very "intuitive" sense-- that is, sometimes it just helps me to use that particular term for this operation because it's just how I understand it best. That might hold true for others, too.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my smart aleck answer as a shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo -n "Password: "
read given
if (echo "$given" | grep -x ' *I love shell scripting *' > /dev/null) ; then
    echo "Password accepted"
else
    echo "Access denied"
fi
```

To make it secure, you could hash the password:

```
#!/bin/bash
read -s -p "Password: " given
echo
hash=$(echo "$given" | sed 's/^ *//' | sed 's/ *$//' | sha1sum)
if [ "$hash" = "6ee322d4a87ec61912b363e704247a1dbad94975  -" ] ; then
        echo "Password accepted"
else
        echo "Access denied"
fi
```

My point is, in real life, storing passwords plaintext is pretty much always a bad idea (though for this assignment security certainly isn't an issue).  This is a fairly simple example of how to make passwords more secure.

Comment: So here we have a ccan GSOC student, answering a homework question .. with a shell script AND humor. I love it, +1.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Java try the String.trim() method.